# Mysql Queries using Stock Control

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Firstly apologies the title is not exactly the most descriptive.
I am using YII and trying to create a stock system and show this in a cgridview. This is not the important part though. Using two mysql tables `products` and `stock` I am trying to give a count of every product in accordance with the stock table. Here are my tables.

**Product table**
[image]

**Stock table**

[image]

Using the following MySQL I get the desired result.

```
SELECT p.name, COUNT(s.id) as product_count
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN stock AS s ON s.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.stock_method = 1
GROUP BY p.name
```

Please see the outcome, as we can see all products with 0 for those where there is no stock adn 8 for the item where there is stock.

[image]

The issue is the stock table represents multiple stock locations and therefore I need to also add a `WHERE` clause that to look only for `stock_area_id = 1`, as soon as I do this I get only a single row with the count of 8. 
Anyone that can advise what needs to be done, I would be most grateful.

As a sidenote, I have two product types one for example is a candy bar, we buy 100 of these and do not care as and when we sell them, the QTY simply decreases by one (ie stock_method 2) and the one I am currently dealing with, we buy 100 phones, each one is stocked individually as we need to know who gets this phone, these are individually stocked based on serial and are stock_method 1 ie always having a qty of 1 and therefore they need to be summed.

Comment: *The issue is the stock table represents multiple stock locations*, do you want to limit search to that locations or not?!

Comment: Yes I do want only stock with a `stock_area_id` of 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately I never found a solution for this. I eventually got what I needed by changing the database design as the current design made a number of things difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use `HAVING` rather than `WHERE` while `GROUP BY` is used.

Try this query

```
SELECT p.name, COUNT(s.id) as product_count
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN stock AS s ON s.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.name
HAVING p.stock_method = 1 AND stock_area_id = 1
```

Comment: Do you know what `HAVING` even does?

Comment: Is that the right way, to use HAVING instead of WHERE..?

Comment: This seems to result in the same issue of having one one row shown